# Why does the box-shadow property not apply to a <tr> but directly to <td> elements in Edge?

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

When adding `box-shadow` to a `<tr>`, Firefox and Chrome both show it around the entire row, while Edge directly applies it to each `<td>` which ends up looking like grid rather than a continuous row.

Here is a demo of the behaviour:

```css
table tr {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red inset;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>hello</td>
    <td>world</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here are screenshots:

1. How it looks in Firefox

[image: How it looks in Firefox]

2. How it looks in Chrome

[image: How it looks in Chrome]

3. How it looks in Edge

[image: How it looks in Edge]

So it seems like Edge is directly applying the given style to the `<td>` elements under the `<tr>` as if I've set the following:

```css
table td {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red inset;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>hello</td>
    <td>world</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

By experimenting, it also seems like `display: block` appears to fix this and it makes all browsers display the shadow (almost) equally

```css
table tr {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red inset;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>hello</td>
    <td>world</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

1. How `display: block` looks in Firefox

[image: How <code>display: block</code> looks in Firefox]

2. How `display: block` looks in Chrome

[image: How <code>display: block</code> looks in Chrome]

3. How `display: block` looks in Edge

[image: How <code>display: block</code> looks in Edge]

Edge does display the `box-shadow` on the `<tr>` and Firefox and Chrome have a similar white-space on the left and right.

According to the [`box-shadow` draft specifications](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#propdef-box-shadow) it's supposed to be applicable to all elements. I am interested in why Edge does what it does: why does it skip the `<tr>` and apply the CSS directly to `<td>` elements? It seems completely unintuitive - other properties like `border` don't behave this way - if you apply that to a parent, the children don't all get `border`, too.

Comment: note that using display block change the default display of tr (which is `table-row`) so it's inaccurate

Comment: sry, I'm confused - why not simply use border, then?

Comment: Since Edge is going to be based on Chromium, this will be no longer be the case in some near future

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah, I know. But I added this just to illustrate the weird handling here. I don't think any other `display` type works in Edge, only `block` seems to make it behave like the rest of the browsers.

Comment: @AnduAndrici I'm asking for an explanation of why this happens because I am curious, not for what to do *instead*. As it stands this behaviour seems illogical to me. But perhaps there is some explanation, which is what I'm after here.

Comment: So, What exactly do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I would vote for a *weird* bug, by the way here is an illustartion of what I meant by *inaccurate* https://jsfiddle.net/xyrt4d8w/ (notice that there is no more table behavior and it's like having divs)

Comment: @xTrimy to hopefully understand *why* Edge does this and in the process enrich my knowledge of both CSS and engines that render it. Perhaps Edge is implementing some earlier draft. or perhaps there is something different - I looked around and found few issues reported with `box-shadow` that implied that the property is somehow lined with `block` level elements, so *maybe* Edge is not entirely incorrect. Or the other browsers are not entirely correct. Or both. Or neither. I don't know which is the case right now.

Comment: I'd suggest to not try to understand the logic behind IE's and Edge's rendering. Lest you wanna go mad. Microsoft is very lazy and/or ignorant, let's just keep it that. Like already mentioned by others, it has a good reason why Edge will switch to Chrome's engine. In the meantime, just look for workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

Limited CSS properties applying to `<tr>` elements (and other elements with "display:table-row") has been the way things are since CSS first became available. More CSS3 properties are listed in the specs as applying to "all elements," but apparently Edge is making that apply to the cells instead of the row itself.