# Validation of range input in Microsoft Edge with values below 0

Tags: javascript, html, validation, range, microsoft-edge

I found something strange while using Microsoft Edge. I have an input element of type range where the user can select values from 0.5 to 0.8 in steps of 0.1. When 0.5 or 0.8 is selected the form validates as expected. If 0.6 or 0.7 the validation returns false and the validation message for this field says that I have to enter a valid date.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkForm() {
    msg = (document.getElementById('myForm').checkValidity()) ? "OK" : "ERROR"
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = msg + ': ' + document.getElementById('field').validationMessage;
  }
</script>


<form id="myForm">
  <input type="range" min="0.5" max="0.8" step="0.1" value="0.6" labels="0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8" id="field" name="field">
  <input type="button" name="save" value="Submit" onClick="checkForm()" />
</form>
<div id="message"></div>
```

The problem only occurs in Microsoft Edge (without Chromium rendering engine). Chrome, Firefox and Mobile Chrome are working as expected. When I change the range from 5 to 8 with steps 1 even Edge is working.

I'm running out of ideas ...

https://jsfiddle.net/7zwpbtok/

Comment: If you don't have to fix it *now*, you might just wait. non-Chromium Edge is essentially being phased out. So, it's possible that this wouldn't be an issue soon. I also [saw an issue in Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55748930/) but was advised to just wait it out, essentially. Probably for the better.

Comment: I know. But this can take a long while because I'm working in a large enterprise environment and everything is so slow here. We still got IE7 when IE9 was released. And then it took a while to upgrade to IE9 (near release of IE10).

Comment: I reproduced the issue on Edge Legacy. I also tried with `min="0.4" max="0.7" step="0.1"` and now 0.4 and 0.6 is OK. It seems it has some issue while calculating these validations and I can't find rules to follow. This might be a issue with Edge Legacy browser and you could try to give feedback in Feedback Hub. But I'm not sure if it'll be fixed in a foreseeable period for the new Edge Chromium is released. You could explain what you want to achieve and we can see if there's any workaround.

Comment: As a workaround for my problem I decided to use integers. As the selected value is a factor for a multiplikation I multiple the number I receive from the database (e.g. 0.6) by 100 and after the user selects a new value I divide it by 100 before storing into the database. So the user now selects a percentage value and not a factor. The result is the same but Edge can handle this as well as all the other browsers.

Comment: Great! You could put the solution as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround for my problem I decided to use integers. As the selected value is a factor for a multiplikation I multiple the number I receive from the database (e.g. 0.6) by 100 and after the user selects a new value I divide it by 100 before storing into the database. So the user now selects a percentage value and not a factor. The result is the same but Edge can handle this as well as all the other browsers.